# "Before putting the agreement to bed, we still had to satisfy them." — What does "to put the agreement to bed" mean: to achieve it or to complete it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-something-to-bed):

> to put something to bed — to achieve a plan or task or complete it successfully:
> **(1)** *Before putting the agreement to bed, we still had to satisfy them*.

Am I right that:
According to the definition, "to put the agreement to bed" can mean two different things: "to achieve the agreement" or "to complete the agreement". That is, the meaning of the sentence is ambigious.

Comment: I don't see how those are two different meanings. Agreements are "put to bed" when they are formally executed.Verbal agreements do not hold if the written agreement says that it, and it alone, is the full agreement between the parties regardless of what may have been said or represented during the pre-agreement negotiation phase. "Achieving agreement" can occur well before bedtime.

Comment: @TimR "to achieve the agreement" = "to come to the agreement"; "to complete the agreement" = "to complete the agreement which the parties came to / achieved before" — so, "to achieve the agreement" and "to complete the agreement" are two different things, aren't they?

Comment: Also, we "achieve agreement" not "achieve *the* agreement".  *The parties achieved agreement and had their attorneys draft a contract*.

Comment: I feel like this almost strays from the topic of language because agreements are between humans and humans are not consistent. I.e. an agreement is inherently ambiguous right up until all involved parties concur that something is done, and that could include deciding that it doesn't need to be done after all!

Comment: to put [a newspaper or publication] to bed comes from the world of print news/magazines and books (publications). It is not usually used for a contract. But in speech, anything is possible and you should **post a link*. But issues can be put to bed.

Comment: "Put x to bed" has spilled over from journalism into corporate culture at large and I've heard it criticized as a cliché or "buzz-speak" in that context. I'm still confused, as perhaps are others, on the difference that "achieve" and "complete" mean to you. "Put to bed" definitely means "complete": "wrap up" without any "loose ends"; conclude in such a way that one can leave work and go to sleep. I'm not sure how "achieve" is different for you. But if your question is really about "put to bed," and the talk about "agreements" is unrelated, maybe edit to use a different example.

Comment: In fact, the fact that the dictionary said that the phrase means "achieve *or* complete" should be evidence that it's regarding the two as close enough in meaning that they can both parallel the same phrase. If we're going to be very particular, I disagree with the dictionary's wording; I would say that "achieve" isn't usually used with "plan or task." "Complete" is the more likely verb for those. "Achieve" is for goals, rewards, etc. Which can still be relevant to "put to bed," but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't at all agree with the definition in that dictionary, and their example sentence doesn't help.

*"To put X to bed" means to deal with X such that X doesn't require attention anymore.*

There's nuance to it as well. As X is merely "put to bed" (and not killed, say), it may become a concern again, so the effect isn't necessarily permanent. X is usually an ongoing concern, so the expression often indicates relief.

The expression doesn't at all indicate what happened to make it no longer a concern, and it's incorrect to define it with more specific verbs like "achieve" or "complete". It's not idiomatic, for instance, to "achieve an issue" or "complete an issue", but "issue" is one of the most common objects used in this expression, as in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-to-bed)'s example:

> We thought we'd put the issue to bed, but it was brought up again at the next meeting.

Without more context, it's not clear here what happened to "put the issue to bed". Maybe they discussed it and came to a resolution, or they threatened to kill anyone who discussed it at future meetings. But it's pretty sure they neither "achieved" nor "completed" it.

In your example sentence from Collins (not reliable, IMO), "the agreement" means a formal contract, so putting the agreement to bed probably means something like "complete negotiations" or "sign the document", but it could also mean to "walk away from the agreement" or otherwise make the agreement impossible to complete. As in:

> Before **walking away from the agreement**, we still had to satisfy them.